# centering - background image & width auto

Tags: html, css, centering

I have a button that spans the full width of a screen:

```
<button class="btn btn-default"> 
  <div class="center-copy">
    <p class="answer-copy-1">accusantium quia sunt</p>
    <p class="question-results">44%</p> 
  </div>     
</button>
```

I would like the text in the first paragraph tag to be centered, with its background image next to the text.  The problem is when that first `<p>` is centered, the background image is not directly next to the text. It will appear at the far left of the button.

Here is the CSS:

```
.btn-default {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    color: #333333;
}

.center-copy{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

p.answer-copy-1{
    background-image: url("http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/greg/imgs/dots.png");
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.question-results{
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtian/wrN9A/

Comment: Some of you code missing? Did you forget to use the code-tag for
 "I would like the (?) 
to be centred"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try the following:

for the paragraph with the background "dot", add `display:inline-block`, to keep it centered so the background will snap to the left of the pararaph.

Then put a `padding-left` so the text won't be over the background image.

If you wish to have the dot before the centered text, add a additional negative `margin-left`, so the text itself will be at absolute center again.

Like this:

```
p.answer-copy-1 {
    display:inline-block;
    background: url("http://demo.omnigon.com/christian_bovine/greg/imgs/dots.png") left top no-repeat;
    padding-left:15px;
    margin-left:-15px;          
}
```

See the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wrN9A/1/

Answer (score 0):

Your background image is aligned to the left side of the paragraph, which is 100% of the width of it's parent.  This is why the dot appears to the far left of the text. You can try adjusting the starting position of background image.  Ex:

```
background-position: 11em 0;
```

A more flexible solution would be to use [CSS generated content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content) - you could add an element exactly where you want it, and style it - particularly if your colored dot is really **content** rather than **styling**.